# Is it safe to use more than 1500 tabs in a TabLayout?

Tags: android

I am using an adapter with 1000+ items in it. Does this cause lag? It seems like it might - but it could be my imagination. If it does how can I get around it? I want to have a tab for each month in many years

Code:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(564);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Comment: try doing it. let us know how it behaves

Comment: I don't see any user browsing 1500 tabs in an app...

Comment: Did you try looping the tabs? It is a better and efficient than using 1500 tabs.

Comment: Its not really meant for users to browse all of them its more so users can see the month they are filtering by

Comment: wonderful design! ui designer for this idea must be given a medal. Anyways in case if you find it laggy, use offscreenpagelimit property of viewpager to load only two pages when the user swipes through the tabs.

Comment: @Abhi Do you know how to loop tabs? I couldnt find any documentation on it

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki My idea actually, but im pretty sure Google does the same. Cant remember where I saw it tho

Comment: You can use [this library](https://github.com/Cleveroad/LoopBar) or [this](https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout) which does the work easily and elegantly.

Comment: @Abhi I was thinking of using this: https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2220 - wasn't sure if it is outdated though or still needed

Comment: The library seems active and would most probably resolve your issue. Why not use it then?

Comment: @Abhi I wasnt sure if Android had already made a solution but yeah I guess i will thanks

Comment: Android does have a solution but it would be a lot more work.